# How create a struct to store datetime and filename from a dir in C language?

Tags: c, struct, operating-system, filenames, dirent.h

I'm trying to create a struct to store filename and datatime of files from a dir

```
  if(dir)
{
  struct dirent *file;
  struct stat info_;
  char buf[256];
  int N=0;

  struct element
  {
      char *name;
      time_t date;
  };
  struct element database[N];

  while ( (file=readdir(dir)) != NULL )
  {
    if(file->d_name[0] != '.')
    {
     strcpy(database->name, file->d_name);
     database->date=info_.st_mtime;
     N++;
     }
    }


    int i;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
      printf("%s",database->name);
      printf("%d",database->date);  
    }
```

I'd like also to sort the struct but It's an other problem that come after this.
The program give me segmentation fault. I'm not very sure that the struct is correct. How can I modify it? Thx

Comment: `int N=0; ...  struct element database[N];` no wonder why it crashes...

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, I think it's obvious why it gives you segfault.

```
 int N=0;
 struct element database[N];
```

Now watch carefully what have you done. You created an array with 0 elements and you try to store something in it.

```
  strcpy(database->name, file->d_name);
```

Your array must contain enough space to store the name you wanted to store in it.

The best way to achieve that is using dynamically alocated space with `malloc()`;

Comment: ok but it doesn't work anyway. Do you think that `strcpy(database->name, file->d_name);` and `database->date=info_.st_mtime;` used for store the data are correct?

Comment: I used `char *name[20];` but it give me segfault again

Comment: I changed the declaration in `struct element *database = malloc(sizeof(struct element) * tbuffer);` but I think that the real problem is here: `strcpy(database->name[20], s_dir->d_name);`

Comment: Oh well, yet again you can't use strcpy(database->name[20], ....) but strcpy (database->name, ....) Because when you write name[20] you are going to write on the 20th place in the array out of 20. Which means, you don't have enough memory again.